# R Binary file query

Tags: r, file, binary

I am trying to create binary file by using R program.  I tried the following program from the internet.

**Program**

```
``df = data.frame(
  "ID" = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  "Name" = c("Tony", "Thor", "Loki", "Hulk"),
  "Age" = c(20, 34, 24, 40),
  "Pin" = c(756083, 756001, 751003, 110011)
)
 
con = file("myfile.dat", "wb")
writeBin(colnames(df), con)
writeBin(c(df$ID, df$Name, df$Age, df$Pin), con)
close(con)`
`
```

I got the myfile.dat file with unreadable characters (Opened in Notepad).

**Output File myfile.dat:**

䑉一浡e杁e楐n1234潔祮吀潨r潌楫䠀汵k〲㌀4㐲㐀0㔷〶㌸㜀㘵〰1㔷〱㌰㄀〱㄰1

I added one more record to the data frame. The changed program is shown below.

**Changed Program**

```
`df = data.frame(
  "ID" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  "Name" = c("Tony", "Thor", "Loki", "Hulk", "Jeff"),
  "Age" = c(20, 34, 24, 40, 45),
  "Pin" = c(756083, 756001, 751003, 110011, 110012)
)

con = file("myfile.dat", "wb")
writeBin(colnames(df), con)
writeBin(c(df$ID, df$Name, df$Age, df$Pin), con)
close(con)`
```

I got the myfile.dat file with perfectly readable characters (Opened in Notepad).

ID Name Age Pin 1 2 3 4 5 Tony Thor Loki Hulk Jeff 20 34 24 40 45 756083 756001 751003 110011 110012

**My queries** 1) If binary files are not supposed to be human readable, how come the file myfile.dat generated by the above R program is perfectly human readable in Notepad?

2. How come there are different outputs when 1 more record is added to the R data frame?

Thank You.

I executed the programs and got different outputs. I could not figure why the output of the first program was not readable whereas the output of the second program was readable when the file was opened in notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2. How come there are different outputs when 1 more record is added to the R data frame?
   This is more a question of how notepad guesses what it is looking at; with the short version my notepad is guessing UTF-16 LE; whereas the longer it guesses UTF-8 ;
   my notepad++ guesses windows/ansi for both; and so is more consistent.

1. I don't have all the answers and ins and outs but I believe you can get to the raw bits in the following sort of way when manually file exporting R.

```
colnames(df)
paste0(colnames(df),collapse = ";")
charToRaw(paste0(colnames(df),collapse = ";"))
(mybits <- rawToBits(charToRaw(paste0(colnames(df),collapse = ";"))))

con = file("myfile.dat", "wb")
writeBin(mybits, con)
close(con)
```